# Read xml element with simpleXML in php with name which contain :

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXML in PHP  and I tried to parse xml file which contain : in element name, like this:

```
<url>
  <url1> url </url>
  <data:data> some data </data:data>
</url>
```

main problem is I can't parse element whith such name ( `<data:data>` ), I tried `$xml->url->{'data:data'};` but I got no effect. When I tried to find out all `<ulr>` childred with

```
foreach ($url->children() as $key ) {
                 echo $key->getName() ;
    }
```

I got only one child, can anyone help me how to parse xml whith : in name.
I tried change `<data:data>` to `<data-data>` then `{'data-data'}` worked, but this insnt solution for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A name that contains ":" in XML is considered a namespace which needs to be defined.

Straight from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) of `SimpleXMLElement::children` example #2.

```
$xml = '<example xmlns:foo="my.foo.urn">
  <foo:a>Apple</foo:a>
  <foo:b>Banana</foo:b>
  <c>Cherry</c>
</example>';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$kids = $sxe->children('foo');
var_dump(count($kids));
```

Comment: That needs to be `$kids = $sxe->children('foo', true);` (trusting the document-assigned prefix not to change) or `$kids = $sxe->children('my.foo.urn');` (using the actual namespace identifier, which should never change).